# Remove Cells from a Defined Range

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is relatively simple: I'm attempting to create a named range by taking the Active Sheet's Used Range but excluding Column A.

Essentially I'm attempting to figure out how to do the opposite of a Union.

How would I go about this?

Thank you.

I haven't tried any solutions as none of the solutions I've found on Google or here on StackExchange are applicable to my current situation. All of them are highly specific, and I just need a general answer on how to remove cells from a defined range.

Comment: Use [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba) to help you find the last column and last row.  Then you can use that to set your range starting at B1 and ending with the last column and last row.

Comment: There is no function that would do the opposite of `Union`. When you need it, you handle it differently from case to case. In your case, to reference the used range without the first column, you could do something like `Set rg = ws.UsedRange.Resize(, ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Sub RangeMinusFirstColumn()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
    Set rng = rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.Count - 1)

End Sub
```